# Angular Material: equal styling for mat-sort-headers and non mat-sort-headers

Tags: angular, angular-material

I recently noticed that my column headers are not aligned horizontally. I figured out what causes it, but I don't know how to fix it exactly.

**What I currently have**

[image: Situation as is]

This is currently so because the HTML contains the following code

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
   <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="Status">
     Status
     ... <!-- Unimportant information -->
   </mat-header-cell>
     ... <!-- Unimportant information -->
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="Actions">
   <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> <!-- Notice how mat-sort-header is not present, this causes the visual issue -->
     Acties
   </mat-header-cell>
    ... <!-- Unimportant information -->
</ng-container>
```

**What I want to achieve**

[image: What I want to achieve]

Is easily doable by adding `mat-sort-header="Status"` to the `Acties` HTML code. However, this causes another issue, being the following error message (see image 3).

[image: Error caused by adding mat-sort-header="Status"]

**What I tried already**

- I tried adding the `mat-sort-header` class styling to my `Acties` column but this doesn't fix it since the `mat-sort-header` also generates other HTML (button etc.).
- Adding `mat-sort-header="status"` (lowercase status) to my `Acties` HTML, but then it'll mess with sorting but not throw an error.
- Adding `mat-sort-header=""` (empty) to my `Acties` HTML, but then it'll mess with sorting, and sort on `Acties` instead which is not possible, but not throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do a /deep/ styling selector and give the "acties" a class or id and target it with the rule you need?

```
/deep/ mat-header-cell.acties {
// your rules here
}
```

Comment: Actually, yes and no. I just discovered that it was my own CSS causing the issue. A button had a default `margin-top` of 15px and the `mat-sort-header` code generates a button in the column header. This caused all sortable colums to be off by 15px. I had to override my own CSS using the `::ng-deep` selector so that is where your answer came in handy.

Comment: @RubenSzekér - could you please share your final code. I am running into similar issue, please see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76203920/mat-table-misaligned-headers