# mat-table misaligned headers

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

When `mat-table` is re-rendered with more columns, some of it's headers(see how `column4` and `Column5` are not on the same line as Column1,2,3 and Column6) gets misaligned with others, like the following image. what could I do to improve the situation?

[image]

All the header columns have similar styling, see below element details.

```
<th _ngcontent-sjy-c336="" role="columnheader" mat-header-cell="" mat-sort-header="" class="mat-sort-header mat-header-cell cdk-header-cell ng-tns-c221-155 cdk-column-column2 mat-column-column2 ng-star-inserted mat-table-sticky mat-table-sticky-border-elem-top" ng-reflect-id="" aria-sort="none" style="top: 0px; z-index: 100;">
    <div class="mat-sort-header-container mat-focus-indicator ng-tns-c221-155" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-5" cdk-describedby-host="0" tabindex="0" role="button">
        <div class="mat-sort-header-content ng-tns-c221-155"> Column2 </div>
        <div class="mat-sort-header-arrow ng-trigger ng-trigger-arrowPosition ng-tns-c221-155 ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(25%);">
            <div class="mat-sort-header-stem ng-tns-c221-155"/>
            <div class="mat-sort-header-indicator ng-tns-c221-155 ng-trigger ng-trigger-indicator" style="transform: translateY(0px);">
                <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-left ng-tns-c221-155 ng-trigger ng-trigger-leftPointer" style="transform: rotate(-45deg);"/>
                <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-right ng-tns-c221-155 ng-trigger ng-trigger-rightPointer" style="transform: rotate(45deg);"/>
                <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-middle ng-tns-c221-155"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}-->
    </div>
</th>
```

**Note** - I realize I may not have provided everything please do let me know what I need to share so you can provide your feedback.

Comment: Providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), for example on stackblitz, is usually your best bet when asking the question.

Comment: Thanks @TotallyNewb - I  kind of figured out my own as to what had been going on, and might post the answer for fellows like me to get benefit of. I haven't used stackblitz in past, but I see lot of people post their code using that, maybe it is time for me to start using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I `inspected` the element using `chrome's developer tool`. I found out that a very specific rule was applied so I had to do the following to get what I needed.

**CSS Code -**

```
th.mat-header-cell {
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: center;
}

td.mat-cell:last-of-type{
    text-align-last: left;
}
```

I hope it helps someone.